# Using Python File Operations

Tags: python

So I have two scripts. Main.py, which is ran upon startup and is ran in the background. otherscript.py which is ran whenever the user invokes it.

main.py crunches some data then writes it out to a file every iteration of the while loop. (this data is about ~ 1.17 mb), and erases old data. So data.txt contains the latest crunched data.

otherscript.py will read data.txt (the current data at that instant) then do something with it.

main.py

```
while True:
    file = "data.txt"
    data = crunchData()
    file.write(data)
```

otherscript.py

```
data = file.read("data.txt")
doSomethingWithData(data)
```

How can I make the connection between the two scripts process faster? Are there any alternatives to file writing the data?

Comment: what is `data`? a string? why do you need two separate scripts? And why do you have a `while True`? Does the result of `crunchData` change over time?

Comment: I need two scripts because otherscript.py is ran whenever the user wants and needs to get the latest data.

Comment: I wouldn't call your variable `file`. It's really a filename and there is a python primitive named `file` for operating on files which your code would conflict with.

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows, mac, linux?

Comment: "How can I make the connection between the two scripts process faster?" That depends -- What is currently the slow part? file IO? serialization? How do you serialize the numpy array?

Comment: Basically writing to a file every iteration is not great. I am using str to sterilize the array.

Comment: I guess both contribute to the slowness but there must be a faster way than constantly writing data to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of [Inter-Process Communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). In your case, you basically have a producer process, and a consumer process.

One way of doing IPC, as you've found, is using files. However, it'll saturate the disk quickly if there's lots of data going through.

If you had a straight consumer that wanted to read all the data all the time, the easiest way to do this would probably be a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) - at least if you're on a unix platform (mac, linux).

If you want a cross-platform solution, my advice, in this case, would be to use a [socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket). Basically, you open a network port on the producer process, and every time a consumer connects, you dump the latest data. You can find a simple how-to on sockets [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html).

Comment: I remove the data and add the new data every iteration, so there isn't too much file space being used.

Comment: @KingofGames The problem is not the used space, but the speed at which the data is generated. A common disk writes at 50-100 MB/s, so, depending on your data, it's not difficult to saturate the bus

Comment: Hmm, which IPC would you think be the fastest for my situation? I was looking into mmaps which seem to work well.

Comment: As I mentioned, if you want a cross-platform solution, you're better off using a socket. a mmap means you'll still using files. You can always try both alternatives and see what's best

Comment: doesn't mmap use ram hence making it faster?